# Implementing delegate methods based on SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I need to work with the MapKit.framework for my latest project. I saw in the apple documentation that based on the running iOS Version i need to implement `mapView:rendererForOverlay:` (iOS7) or `mapView:didAddOverlayViews:` (since iOS4). I'd like to also support versions < 7.0. So how can i implement both delegate methods based on the running OS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before iOS 7, the delegate method to implement for overlay views was `mapView:viewForOverlay:` (not `mapView:didAddOverlayViews:`).

To handle any iOS version, you don't need to actually check the version number in your code.

Instead, just implement both the `mapView:viewForOverlay:` and the `mapView:rendererForOverlay:` methods.

When the app is running on an iOS lower than iOS 7, it will call `mapView:viewForOverlay:`.

When the app is running on iOS 7 or higher, it will call `mapView:rendererForOverlay:` (if it's implemented).

If you implement *only* `mapView:viewForOverlay:`, iOS 7 currently *will* still call the old, deprecated method if `mapView:rendererForOverlay:` is not also implemented.